# ASP Core 2 How to change (update) claim for active user

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core

I have an application where user profile drives claims collection.

When user change the profile (added a new module) the corresponding claim should be updated.

How I can do it for Core2 ?

Thanks,
Oleg

Comment: Claims are stored in the authentication cookie, if you want to change a claim you need to sign the user out and then sign them in again

Comment: Thanks.It works.

Comment: You should post that as an answer then, I just wanted to point you in the right direction